# Unable to setup environment variable in terraform local-exec provisioner running through Atlantis (Terraform Pull Request Automation) tool

Tags: bash, kubernetes, terraform, terragrunt

I have successfully deployed AKS Using Terragrunt through Atlantis, Now I want to set credentials to communicate with the Kubernetes API Server.

For that, I am setting up the **KUBECONFIG** Environment variable to authenticate with Kubernetes.

Below is the code that will run in Atlantis Container, so that we will have one-click deployment of pods or helm after setting credentials through Terraform code only.

```
resource "null_resource" "null" {
 provisioner "local-exec" {
   command = <<-EOT
    echo "$(terraform output kube_config)" > ~/.kube/azurek8s # Storing kube config credential file for kube api server authentication
    sed -i '1d;$d' ~/.kube/azurek8s # delete 1st and last line from output
  EOT
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
   command = "export KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/azurek8s" # setting up env variable for kubeconfig
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
   command = "env"
  }
}
```

After setting up the environment variable, I have added the env command to check whether actually environment variable is set or not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Each `local-exec` will execute in its own shell environment, so there is no persistence between the second and third executions of your `local-exec`.

To set environment variables for your `local-exec`, you should use [environment](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/local-exec.html#environment):

```
  provisioner "local-exec" {
   command = "env"
   environment = {
       KUBECONFIG = "~/.kube/azurek8s"
   }
```